# <a href ="www.xyz.com">XYZ </a> Not working in android

Tags: android, html, tags, textview, clickable

i have searched on Stack overflow and followed the solution but still not getting what i want.
i am receiving String from server like this

```
  <p><a href="http://www.arenafootball.com/sports/a-footbl/aflsrk/mtt/micheaux_robinson_841978.html"><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>AFL Stats</strong></span></a></p>
```

and now i am trying to display it in `TextView` in android using`tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(""))`

**Code:**

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("myrecivedString"));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**XML:**

```
 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:autoLink="all"
   android:linksClickable="true" />
```

Expected output:

[**AFL Stats**](http://www.arenafootball.com/sports/a-footbl/aflsrk/mtt/micheaux_robinson_841978.html)

its clickable but in my android app the output is not clickable .what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tv.setText( Html.fromHtml("your string"));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and don't use `android:autoLink="all"` on TextView in XML. then try it should work.....